# what is the difference between dbms_output, output variable, output script and output result in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, return-value, oracle12c, dbms-output

I'm a bit confuse. What is difference between dbms_output, output variable, output script and output result in oracle.

Because I want to write a stored procedure in Oracle. Then, the stored procedure will be executed from my typescript codes. But. I'm a bit confuse where and how to return the result. is it from output variable or using dbms_output only? Please help

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_OUTPUT will display result on the screen (if SERVEROUTPUT is set to ON; otherwise, you won't see it). Moreover, it requires you to execute that procedure from some tool that is capable of *seeing* DBMS_OUTPUT's result. These would be SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD and similar tools. If you use it in, for example, Apex, you won't see anything.

If these *typescript codes* you use (I don' know what that is) won't allow you to see it, you'll have to use a variable or store the result into a table (so that you could select it later), send it via e-mail (if possible) etc.